# Swift macos - открыть окно терминала и перейти по пути

Tags: swift, консоль, macos, shell

цель проста:

1. открыть окно терминала
2. перейти в некую локацию

мой код:

```
public class func openShell(at url: URL?) {
    guard let url = url else { return }
    
    let shellProcess = Process();

    shellProcess.launchPath = url.path;

    //shellProcess.arguments = [
    //  "osascript -e 'tell application \"terminal\" to do script \"cd \(url)\"'"
    //];

    shellProcess.launch();
}
```

просто выдает ряд текста в debug output XCode и все.

Закомментированый код - альтернативное решение которое так же не сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для открытия терминала используйте `NSWorkspace`:

```
@available(OSX 10.15, *)
public class func openTerminal(at url: URL?){
    guard let url = url,
          let appUrl = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Terminal")
    else { return }
    
    NSWorkspace.shared.openFile("\(url.path)", withApplication: appUrl.path)
}
```

Скрипт можете сделать как отельным файлом и вытягивать из Bundle, так и в коде.